# First setting a SESSION variable through ajax, and then using it upon visiting page

Tags: php, ajax, session, cors

I want to POST a string across domains by using AJAX and CORS after a mouse click, and when the POST is successful use that string as a SESSION variable. When ajax fires the done() event, I then want to open a new tab to the domain we posted to earlier and use the SESSION variable.

### What I want to achieve, summarised

- a user is on site A
- site A does a POST request to page A on site B where it wants to post a string to
- page A on site B stores the string in a SESSION variable
- upon success the browser opens a new tab to page B on site B
- page B on site B looks for the SESSION variable and uses it if present

Even though I was initially planning on solving this with a SharedWorker support does not seem to be quite right for it. Just using a URL parameter / a GET is not possible either because I fear that the size of the data can get too long.

### What I have

`php/receive-post.php` on domain B

```
<?php
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

    if ($origin == 'http://site.a.com') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control');

        if (isset($_POST)) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['string'] = $_POST['string'];
          echo json_encode($_SESSION['string']);
          session_write_close();
        }
    }
```

Relevant code from `index.php` on domain B

```
<?php
    $string;
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    if (isset($_SESSION['string'])):
        $string= $_SESSION['string'];
    else:
        $string= 'I like bananas';
    endif;
    session_write_close();
    echo $string;
?>
```

And the script from domain A (jQuery)

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  postString($("textarea").serialize(), href);
});

function postString(myString, href) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain.a.com/receive-post.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: myString,
    headers: {
      'cache-control':' no-cache'
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a + b + c);
  }).always(function() {
    console.log("always");
    var newTab = window.open(href, '_blank');
    if (newTab) {
      newTab.focus();
    } else {
      alert('Your browser blocked opening a new window.');
    }
  });
}
```

### What happens

What should happen is that after clicking the link on domain A, a new tab is opened and de SESSION variable is used on there. However, this is not what happens.

The POSTing of the data works, as I can verify in console on domain B that the returned value of the SESSION variable is indeed set. The new tab is also opened. However, the SESSION variable is not used/set on that page. A `var_dump($_SESSION)` returns an empty array, meaning that there are no SESSION variables set.

Why is that? Why isn't the SESSION variable carried from page A to page B on domain B? And how do I make it usable?

Comment: `$_SESSION['string'] = $_POST['string];` Check this you havent closed the post variable properly. Is it typo or is it the issue.

Comment: @Sasikumar Sorry that was a typo here on SO. Original code does not have that issue.

Comment: R u getting the return response from the ajax over the cross domain request.

Comment: You need to add `withCredentials` (see jQuery.ajax docs), otherwise cookies won’t be send/accepted for cross-domain requests.

Comment: @CBroe Cheers, that was it. (Together with the corresponding `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header in `receive-post.php`.) If you could post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `withCredentials` (see jQuery.ajax docs, xhrFields), otherwise cookies won’t be send/accepted for cross-domain requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials:

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. […] In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response.

---

And as you said, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` needs to be added to the response from the remote domain, to tell that browser that it is allowed to include credentials in cross-domain requests to this URL.